# Why php memcached layer is not hashing my key as expected?

Tags: php, hash, memcached

i'm using **php5-memcached** (libmemcached version: 1.0.8)

After reading this man page
http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php

i understand that keys passed at [get](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.get.php) and [set](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php) methods are hashed while talking to memcached, and that the default hasing algorithm is "Jenkins has function"

> Memcached::OPT_HASH
>   Specifies the hashing algorithm used for the item keys. The valid values are supplied via Memcached::HASH_* constants. Each hash algorithm has its advantages and its disadvantages. Go with the default if you don't know or don't care.
>
> Type: integer, default: Memcached::HASH_DEFAULT
>
> Memcached::HASH_DEFAULT
>   The default (Jenkins one-at-a-time) item key hashing algorithm.

But when i try to use a key with an invalid memcached char (such as space char) the memcached item seems not created.

To be sure, I

```
service memcached restart
```

then I set my cache item

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$m->set("pesce azzurro", "ciao!", time() + 14400)
var_dump($m->getResultCode());
```

the action failes with error 9 that should be

> 09 = MEMCACHED_CLIENT_ERROR

Just to check I try

```
 echo "stats items" | nc localhost 11211
```

and the output says that there are no items

```
END
```

So my question is, why php memcached layer is not hasing my key as expected?
Should I externaly hash my keys width md5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key itself is not hashed, so you still have to use a valid key name.

A hashed version of the key is used to determine which server in a cluster the key should be stored on / retrieved from. If you have two servers, keys with a MD5 hash starting in 0-7 might wind up on server 1, and keys with hashes starting in 8-f might wind up on server 2, *but those servers will store the data under the unhashed key itself*.